# Serialize member types without using XmlInclude in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am carrying out XML Serialization in .NET

I have the following class

```
public class MainClass
{
    public ClassA A;
}

public class ClassA { }

public class ClassB : ClassA { }

public class ClassC : ClassA { }
```

When I am calling `Serialize` method of `XmlSerializer` on an object of MainClass, I am getting exception that is suggesting to make use of `XmlInclude` attribute. I don't want to use the attributes option.

`Serialize` method has an overload that takes array of Type to specify the sub-types of the type (MainClass in above example) on which serialization is being carried out. Using this overload we can avoid the need to mark the class with `XmlInclude` attribute.

Can similar thing be done with members of the type (MainClass in above example) being serialized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainClass),
    new[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassB), typeof(ClassC) });
ser.Serialize(writer, new MainClass { A = new ClassB() });
```

**Result:**

```
<MainClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <A xsi:type="ClassB" />
</MainClass>
```

---

Alternatively, you could add the attributes programmatically:

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
// Add [XmlElement]'s to MainClass.A
overrides.Add(typeof(MainClass), "A", new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlElements = {
        new XmlElementAttribute() { Type = typeof(ClassA) },
        new XmlElementAttribute() { Type = typeof(ClassB) },
        new XmlElementAttribute() { Type = typeof(ClassC) },
    }
});

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainClass), overrides, null, null, null);
ser.Serialize(writer, new MainClass { A = new ClassB() });
```

**Result:**

```
<MainClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ClassB />
</MainClass>
```

Comment: I want to avoid attributes as I said in my question. I know about this solution. Is there some way this can be done without using attributes ?